# Seperate maps of nested objects using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to put nested objects into a flatten DTO. I'm not in control of naming neither DTO or business objects, so renaming/restructure those are not a possibility unfortunately.

Here is an example of my case:

```
//Domain Objects
public class Order {
  public decimal Total { get; set; }
  public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address {
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}



//Dtos
public class OrderCustomerDTO {
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerStreet { get; set; }
    public string CustomerCity { get; set; }
}


//Mapping profile
public class MapperProfile : AutoMapper.Profile {
    public MapperProfile() {
        CreateMap<Order, OrderCustomerDTO>(MemberList.None)
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Total, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Total));

        CreateMap<Customer, OrderCustomerDTO>(MemberList.None)
            .ForMember(dst => dst.CustomerName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name));   

        CreateMap<Address, OrderCustomerDTO>(MemberList.None)
            .ForMember(dst => dst.CustomerStreet, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Street))        
            .ForMember(dst => dst.CustomerCity, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.City));
    }
}


//Perform mapping
public void MapOrder(IEnumerable<Order> input) {
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.AddProfile<MapperProfile>();
        });
    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    var mapped = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<OrderCustomerDTO>>(input);
}
```

The result of this is that only the OrderCustomerDTO.Total has been populated, and the rest is left as null values.

I was thinking something like linking the maps,  so the previous map links to the next and so on, but this will result in an exception:

```
// Invalid map
public class MapperProfile : AutoMapper.Profile {
    public MapperProfile() {
        CreateMap<Order, OrderCustomerDTO>(MemberList.None)
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Total, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Total))
            .ForMember(dst => dst, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Customer));//Load nested type

        CreateMap<Customer, OrderCustomerDTO>(MemberList.None)
            .ForMember(dst => dst.CustomerName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
            .ForMember(dst => dst, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Address)); //Load nested type

        CreateMap<Address, OrderCustomerDTO>(MemberList.None)
            .ForMember(dst => dst.CustomerStreet, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Street))        
            .ForMember(dst => dst.CustomerCity, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.City));
    }
}
```

This will result throw an exception like:

> An exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException'
>   occurred in AutoMapper.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: Custom configuration for members is only supported for
>   top-level individual members on a type.

Clearly I'm missing something regarding these nested mappings. A solution (an ugly one) is to put it all together in one Map, but this means that I'll have something like:

```
// Ugly map
public class MapperProfile : AutoMapper.Profile {
    public MapperProfile() {
        CreateMap<Order, OrderCustomerDTO>(MemberList.None)
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Total, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Total))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.CustomerName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Customer.Name))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.CustomerStreet, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Customer.Address.Street))       
            .ForMember(dst => dst.CustomerCity, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Customer.Address.City));
    }
}
```

It's clear that this approach doesn't take much to be a mess, and totally not maintainable.

How do I seperate automapper maps of each nested object into it's own map, and still keep a link between the nested object and the top one??

Comment: Have you had a look through [this documentation page](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html) on flattening?

Comment: According to the documentation var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()); does the magic, but as I wrote, this has no effect on my example, as the nested type will be left as null values.

Comment: Hmm. I assume that it's because it's double nested. Perhaps you need `CustomerAddressStreet`

Comment: Interesting thing I discovered after reading it once again. I see that you can define .IncludeMembers() according to the documentation, but I cannot find that method of my AutoMapper, maybe its from a newer version of AM?

Comment: @John The solution has been found. Using .IncludeMemers() will do the trick, and then just define a Map for each member type that you include. I don't know from what version this has been implemented, but I can confirm it works with AM 9

Comment: You should add that as an answer to help others who might have the same issue. :-) If you you do, tag me and I'll upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The solution has been found. Using .IncludeMemers() will do the trick, and then just define a Map for each member type that you include. I don't know from what version this has been implemented, but I can confirm it works with AM 9